# Detect multiline on Excel Cell

Tags: c#, excel, csv, npoi

I'm having some problems converting an `excel` file to `csv` format with `C#` and `NPOI` library.
I have to return an error in case there is a multiline cell like the following

---

|""  |
|text|
|text|

The output of the `csv` file is expected to be:
"",
text,
text,

How can I detect it and `throw` an `error` ?

```
            for (int row = 0; row <= sheet.LastRowNum; row++)
        {
            for (int cell = 0; cell < sheet.GetRow(row).Cells.Count ; cell++)
            {     
                csvData += sheet.GetRow(row).Cells[cell].ToString() + ",";                
            }
            csvData += "\n";
        }
```

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but you don't throw an error, you throw an `Exception`. It isn't the best way to deal with flow of control. Is this multiline condition truly exceptional? Maybe you could return an error code, or log the line numbers of bad lines, and allow the program to continue.

Comment: yes, exactly.. but i can't figure out how to detect if the string contains '\n'

Comment: Have you tried `myString.Contains("\n")`?

Comment: yes, doesn't work.
i have converted that file from excel to a csv data, but i'm unable to check for a multiline cell and throw an exception

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you have tried and explain what you mean by "doesn't work."

Comment: "doesn't work"  mean "myString.Contains("\n")" return always false

Comment: You code example does not contain any reference to `Contains`. Please provide a [MCVE].